# Kinetic Inductance and Magnetic Flux

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, condensed-matter, superconductivity, inductance

Superconductors are known to have kinetic inductance which is the manifestation of the inertial mass of superfluid. In this [link](http://www2.eng.ox.ac.uk/communications/research/ultrafast-electronics/ultrafast-research-projects/kinetic-inductance), the concept is explained as follows:

> When a current flows the electric field adds a small drift velocity
> component to the whole electon distribution which requries the
> electron system to acquire kinetic energy. In a normal or
> superconducting material this kinetic energy is equivalent
> mathematically to the energy invested in creating a magnetic field -
> the energy is effectively stored until the electrons decelerate again. This is often neglected in normal materials as their resistance requires that energy continually be applied to sustain the current due to charge carrier scattering - ohmic resistance.

I am trying to understand the role of kinetic inductance in magnetic flux generation in superconductors. So, let me formulate a conceptual question:

Let us assume that we have two metallic strips: one superconductor and the other normal. They have identical geometries and are carrying exactly the same current.  Under these conditions,
can we say that SC would generate more magnetic flux at a given point as it has an extra inductance term as:

$L_{total} = L_{geometric} + L_{kinetic}$

Or, would that only relate to circuit properties of these strips as magnetic field generated by a constant current is well defined in classical physics and can be calculated with Biot-Savart law?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinetic inductance has zero role in magnetic flux generation in superconductors.

Put some charge on a linearly moving asteroid. Now the charged asteroid moves linearly without resistance, has lot of stored energy because of the motion, does not have lot of energy stored in a magnetic field.

Admittedly asteroid contains tons of electrons, so one could maybe claim that a few of the millions of tons of inertia that an asteroid has, is electromagnetic inertia.

[Is the electromagnetic mass real?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/160264/is-the-electromagnetic-mass-real)

Anyway, for some reason we say that electron has mass 9.10938356 × 10-31 kilograms. We don't say electron has such inductance that it has inertia equivalent to mechanical mass of 9.10938356 × 10-31 kilograms.

Basically, I think that in electrical engineering we often pretend that the mass of charge carriers is zero, and when it is not possible to ignore the mass of charge carriers, then we often pretend that the inductance of the circuit has increased by some amount, instead of charge carriers having some mass.