# Is Abraham-Lorentz Force problem still unresolved?

Tags: electromagnetism

Is [Abraham-Lorentz Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Lorentz_force) problem still unresolved? I've heard from my electrodynamics class that solving the equation of motion with Abraham-Lorentz term causes either pre-acceleration or runaway solution. Have we found a way to obtain a solution that is neither pre-accelerating nor run away?

Comment: have you read the wiki article? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Lorentz_force

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70915/2451 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99285/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Yes, more specifically I was wondering if this method (http://www.physicspages.com/2015/02/12/radiation-reaction-the-abraham-lorentz-force/) is our best method to solve an equation of motion with Abraham-Lorentz Force and external force.

Comment: I thought resolving runaway problem causes preacceleration problem and vice versa. But my professor later told me that resolving runaway problem by setting a proper initial condition naturally solves preacceleration problem too.

Comment: The answer to your question is that the Abraham-Lorentz 'self force' equation is flawed, and that flaw has been rectified.