# What justification is necessary for convolutional variational principles to be considered legitimate?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, potential, variational-principle

I recently asked a related question and was interested in why/or why we cannot use convolutional variational principles in practice or in theory.

Summarizing the points I made in the earlier post:

Generally, we can only formulate the Lagrangian (and Hamiltonian) for "potential" systems, where in the dynamics satisfy the condition that:
$$
m\ddot{\mathbf{x}}=-\nabla V
$$
If this is true, we can formulate a functional which is stationary with respect to the system as:
$$
F[\mathbf{x}]=\int^{t}_0\left(\frac{1}{2}m\dot{\mathbf{x}}(\tau)^2-V(\mathbf{x}(\tau))\right)\,\text{d}\tau
$$

Taking the first variation of this functional yields the dynamics of the system, along with a condition that effectively states that the initial configuration should be similar to the final configuration (variation at the boundaries is zero).

The functional above is an **inner product** based formulation.

Now, given the functional:
$$  
F[\mathbf{x}]=\frac{1}{2}[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}} * D(\mathbf{x})]+\frac{1}{2}[\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}} * \mathbf{Ax}]-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}'(0)\mathbf{x}(t)
$$
With $\mathbf{A}$ symmetric and $\mathbf{x}(0)$ being the initial condition, and:
$$
[\mathbf{f}^{\text{T}} * \mathbf{g}]=\int^{t}_0 \mathbf{f}^{\text{T}}(t-\tau)\mathbf{g}(\tau)\,\text{d}\tau
$$

If we take the first variation and assume **only** that the initial variation is zero, the functional is stationary with respect to:
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{x}(t)}{dt}= \mathbf{Ax}(t)
$$

This is a functional derived by Tonti and Gurtin, it represents a variational principle for linear initial value problems with symmetric state matrices and shows, as a proof of concept, that functionals *can* be derived for non-potential systems, initial value or dissipative systems.

This functional is a **convolution** based formulation.

Now, one might make the argument that these functionals should somehow be related to the "energy" of the system.

We can use Parseval's theorem to come up with such a relationship.

For some function  $\mathbf{x}(t)$, we have:
$$
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\left|\mathbf{x}(\tau)\right|^2\,\text{d}\tau = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\left|\mathbf{X}(\xi)\right|^2\,\text{d}\xi
$$

Where $\mathbf{X}(f)=\mathcal{F}\!\left\lbrace \mathbf{x}(t)\right\rbrace$, the Fourier transform of the signal.

Either of the sides can be said to be the "energy" content of the signal and the left-hand side is the result of an inner product, which implies some relationship between inner products and "energy" content.

One can similarly relate the total frequency content of a real function $\mathbf{x}(t)$ (righ-hand side above) to a convolution using Plancherel's theorem, this shows that convolutions are related to energy as well.

**Now, are there any other arguments as to why convolutions shouldn't be used in a variantional principle context from a physical standpoint?**

Comment: This question (v1) is related to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167027/2451. The answer is again that any deviation from locality in fundamental physics must be well-justified. Without further justification, the non-local formalism of Tonti & Gurtin is only suitable for applied physics, engineering, etc.

Comment: @Qmechanic: My mistake! I think maybe I'm not quite grasping what that means from a mathematical standpoint. I was hoping someone would make a statement about what said justification would entail. I can delete the question if it seems redundant.

Comment: @Qmechanic: I actually have a new comment on this, with regard to justification: convolutions naturally arise in the context of any forced system (as a convolution of the forcing with the fundamental solution). They're also present in boundary problems for PDEs. Really, any instance where a fundamental solution (or Green's function) is being being used results in a convolution. Not really definitive justification, just something to chew on, I guess...