# Lagrangian and Friction

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, conservation-laws, friction

How does lagrangian mechanics explain loss of momentum conservation in presence of friction?
My try is this:
The lagrange equation would then include a generalized force term $Q_i$:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q_i}} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial q_i} = Q_{i}$$
$$\implies \frac{d}{dt}p_i = Q_i + \frac{\partial L}{\partial q_i}$$
Now how do I show that $Q_i + \frac{\partial L}{\partial q_i}$ is never $0$?
Since $Q_i$ is generalized force,
$$Q_i = \sum_{j}\vec{f_j}\cdot \frac{\partial \vec{r}_j}{\partial q_i}$$

Comment: Related: 

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147341/

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/96466/

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/391870/

Comment: $Q_i = \sum_{j}\vec{f_j}\cdot \frac{\partial \vec{r}_j}{\partial q_i}\ne 0~$ because the friction force is not constraint force.  thus even if $\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_i}=0$ you don’t obtain momentum conservation